# Failed to publish API using WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I am unable to publish API in WSO2 API manager 2.6.0 environments. 
Error message is:

Failed to publish Environments
Production and Sandbox
Error while publishing prototype API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name

I did checked API in the DB it exist.
I did searched over the net but did not find any solution on this issue.

Looks like Even after deleting the API, still context URI is persist somewhere so I think I need to delete the context URI - Please suggest

Comment: How did you delete the API?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the API in API publisher and checked in DB as well. but still I am getting this error. Don't know where this context URI is stored.

Comment: what is the exact error you see?

Comment: Please refer my question I have mentioned error message

Answer (score 1):

I found solution -
Even after deleting the API from WSO2 publisher, Looks like API will not completely deleted from WSO2 so I just checked is there API still exist in WSO2 and I found the API in the below mentioned location and deleted.

---

**API Manager\2.6.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api**

---

Now I am able to create new API with the context URI.